# Getting bvm: command not found

Tags: node.js, bit.dev

I've been using bvm to manage my bit versions for a while now, but now suddenly i'm getting `bvm: command not found`.

`bit -v` still gives me the correct output, so bit is still installed...

Tried running `where bvm` to find the binary but then i just get not found as well.

Answer (score 2):

OK, it turns out this is a general issue with updating node version and global packages.

Global packages are apparently linked to a specific version of node, presumably to ensure compatibility, so when you update node version you need to re-install any global packages.

So just run `npm i -g @teambit/bvm` (or yarn/pnpm equivalent, however you originally installed bvm) to re-install bvm and then all will be good.